# Accesing to sqlite shell from lazarus to run a sql script

Tags: sqlite, shell, lazarus

I have  a program in lazarus that read and process data from mysql5 database server then with this data creates a set of tables in sqlite to use it in a android app, in this set of tables there is one that the amount of records is around 12000, when I try to create this tables by using the Sqlite3 dataaccess object in lazarus like TSqlScript to do this creation script take a long time about 8-15 minutes, but executin this script with sqlite shell comand line take only fews seconds, how I Ejecute this script using the shell sqlite3 from lazarus.

Comment: Are you using one transaction around the entire script?

Comment: Please show your `TSqlScript` code.

Comment: ok I upload this at http://daviduh.awardspace.info/Test.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not use explicit transactions, SQLite will automatically wrap each single SQL statement into a transaction, which results in horrible overhead if you are using many statements.

Explicitly use a single transaction around the entire script.

Comment: I am using TSQLite3Connection and TSQLScript components, and add at the begining of script BEGIN TRANSACTION; and at the end of script COMMIT; but when I call the method SQLScript1.Execute;  it takes a long time and when finish do not create anything but when I run the scritp from SQLite expert personal it take only a few moment

Comment: Yes I try it in java and the speed is very fast when use beign transaction and End Transaction without transaccions take along long time, but in lazarus there are not changes in the speed